# Given multiple polynomial equations find a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have read several other threads on Math.SE, including the similarly titled:
[basis of the polynomial vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546152/basis-of-the-polynomial-vector-space)

I've also checked out a video lecture on Youtube by njwildberger, but I simply have not found the right analogy to grasp what a polynomial space is. As such I am not understanding how to find a basis for it. I.e. if given 4 polynomial equations in P3, how does one find a basis?

$P_1 = x^2 + x - 2$

$P_2 = x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 2$

$P_3 = -x^3 - x^2 +2x$

I tried converting each polynomial to a column vector and then finding a basis for the column space, but I don't see that method used on the internet (in various sources). Somehow I think the basis should be reduced to {a0, a1, a2, a3} where each is the coefficient of a different degree of x.

Bonus marks if you can explain what it means (geometrically or visually) to be in the polynomial space of something. (If a function stretches from -inf on the y to +inf on the y, doesn't that mean everything is in the polynomial space?)

Answer (score 1):

Write the coefficients of the elements as linear combination of the standard bases $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ as rows in a matrix, then apply the elementary operations on the rows to get the matrix in row echelon form. Then you can read the rank of the matrix, which is equal to the number of independent elements in your set of polynomials. These elements correspond to the rows which are not zero in your final matrix. Let $Y$ be the set of independent elements in the given set. Then to extend $Y$ to a basis of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ use the final matrix you got from elementary operations, delete the zero rows and add rows so that you make the rank $4$. Then add the correspondent elements of the added rows to Y. For example if you add the row $(0,0,0,1)$ to the matrix, then you should add the element $x^3$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your problem (adding the $\color{gray}{gray \ polynomial}$ term) will make the example a bit easier.

Start with the monomial bases 
$$
\mathcal{M} = \left\{ 1, x, x^{2}, x^{3} \right\},
$$ 
and the polynomial basis 
$$
\mathcal{P} = \left\{ 
-2+x+x^{2}, 2+x+2x^{2}+x^{3}, -x^3 - x^2 + 2 x, \color{gray}{-1 + 2 x - 4 x^2 + 8 x^3} 
\right\}
$$ 
How do we toggle between these bases?

**Polynomial function to monomial function**

The polynomial basis function $\mathcal{P}_{1}=-2+x+x^{2}$ has the state vector $\mathcal{P}_{1} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal{P}}^{T}$. In terms of the monomial basis, $\mathcal{P}_{1} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal{M}}^{T}$. That is

$$
\mathcal{P}_{1}(x) = 
\left[ \begin{array}{r} -2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal{M}}
\cdot
\left[ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ x \\ x^{2} \\ x^{3} \end{array} \right]
=-2+x+x^{2}
$$

The column vectors of the transformation basis $\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{M}$ are the coordinates of the basis functions $\mathcal{P}$ in the monomial basis.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{r|r|r|r}
 -2 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & -1 & -4 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{M}}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{P}}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -2 \\
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{M}}
$$

**Monomial function to polynomial function**

The reverse mapping is handled by the inverse of the transformation matrix. The example shows how the constant term in the monomial basis $\mathcal{M}_{1} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal{M}}^{T}$ is mapped to the linear combination $\frac{1}{85} \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} -27 & 15 & 7 & -1 \end{array} \right]_{\mathcal{P}}^{T}$.

$$
\frac{1}{170}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -54 & 23 & 39 & 7 \\
 30 & 25 & 35 & 15 \\
 14 & 57 & -29 & -27 \\
 -2 & 4 & -8 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{P}}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{M}}
=
\frac{1}{85}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -27 \\
  15 \\
   7 \\
  -1 
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{P}}
$$
Explicitly,
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{1}{85}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 -27 \\
  15 \\
   7 \\
  -1 
\end{array}
\right]_{\mathcal{P}}
%
\cdot
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
  \mathcal{P}_{1}(x) \\
  \mathcal{P}_{2}(x) \\
  \mathcal{P}_{3}(x) \\
  \mathcal{P}_{4}(x) 
\end{array}
\right] \\[3pt]
%
&=
-\frac{27}{85} \mathcal{P}_{1}(x)
+\frac{3}{17}  \mathcal{P}_{2}(x)
+\frac{7}{85}  \mathcal{P}_{3}(x)
-\frac{1}{85}  \mathcal{P}_{4}(x)
%
\end{align}
$$